# Can I use regular expressions in XML Schema element names?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create an XML Schema for the XML produced by a piece of code I was passed. I'll describe a simplified version of my problem. Let's say an XML file produced by this code describes a text document; it would look like this:

```
<document>
  <r1>A line of text</r1>
  <r2 style="bold">Another line which is bold</r2>
  <r3>Yet another line</r3>
</document>
```

And so on. Not the best design, I know - it would be better if the row numbers were attributes, but that's what I have to work with. And it's representing the row numbers that is the problem. Is there some way to write a Schema that lets me specify a regular expression (or similar) for an **element name**? I expect the XSD file would look somehow like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/SimpleSchema" 
        xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/SimpleSchema" 
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="rX" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="style" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

...where "rX" on line 9 is whatever expression is needed to mean "*a name starting with **r** and ending with X, which is an integer*".

I'd rather avoid having to fix the generating code myself, so I'd like to see if it is possible to write a suitable XML Schema first. Thanks in advance to everybody.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XSD requires that element names be specified literally; the kind of declaration I think you have in mind is not supported.

As you have described it (*a name starting with r and ending with X, which is an integer*), the declaration you would like to write would produce an infinite number of element components in the schema; the only grammatical formalism I know that supports this kind of thing is the two-level grammar developed by Aard van Wijngaarden for Algol 68.

So in the short run, your best options appear to be either to change the generating code, or to invent your own notation for your desired declaration and generate a legal XSD schema document from it.

Comment: I think I'll end up doing exactly this.

Answer (score 4):

In XSD 1.1 you could use xs:any to allow an element with any name, and then use assertions to restrict the name to one that matches a regular expression:

```
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assertion test="every $x in * 
                            satisfies matches(local-name($x), '[Rr][0-9]+')"/>
    </xs:complexType>
```

XSD 1.1 is currently implemented in Xerces (beta) and Saxon (9.4).

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure I can use XSD 1.1. Unfortunately my hands are tied about what tools and libraries to use. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not all that familiar with the RegEx capabilities for an XSD file, but the expression itself is fairly simple.

This would capture the "rX" row number.

```
<([Rr][0-9]{1,})>
```

If you cannot utilize a capture group, you could simply use this.

```
[Rr][0-9]{1,}
```