# Using wildcards in XSD element names?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD file as shown below. The problem is the nodes for **City** and **State** are dynamic, and will consist of actual City and State names. Is there any way to use a wildcard name for these elements?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Root">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="State">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="City">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeID" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeState" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeCity" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeStreetName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeZip" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeContact" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cafeEmail" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hasPickup" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="hasDriveThru" type="xs:string" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: So as soon as New York or Des Plaines appears in the data, your client is going to provide you with non-well-formed XML?  Renegotiate.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't let element names vary across an unknown, open-ended domain because you'll frustrate efforts of**

1. **Data modelers** to constrain content models for these elements and of elements containing these elements.
2. **Consumers** of this data to write handlers and transformations for these elements.

If you use XML as a ***markup language*** and markup the city and state names with `city` and `state` elements or attributes, you'll have much less trouble defining an XSD and creating applications for it.

Comment: I understand that, but the source xml file is coming from a client so I don't have any control over it.

Comment: See [XSD element name pattern matching](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25568670/290085) for how to enforce that element names match a pattern, but that's about as far as I'd go with dynamic element names.  In your case, push back on this terrible design, or punt via `xsd:any` (assuming, as [C.M. Sperberg-McQueen alludes to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929416/using-wildcards-in-xsd-element-names/37930632?noredirect=1#comment63312591_37929416), that you're assured that element names will be purely NCNAMEs).

Comment: How would `xsd:any` fix this?

Comment: I said you could [***punt***](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73783/what-do-i-do-now-punt-what-is-meant-by-punt-here/73784)  via `xsd:any` -- not ***fix*** this.