# xml schema list of incremental element name

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd

With xml schema , how can I validate an xml file , that have an incremental element name ?

Example :
xml :

```
<liste_of_element>
    <element_1> ...... </element_1>
    <element_2> ...... </element_2>
    <element_3> ...... </element_3>
</liste_of_element>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a poor XML design, and one of the symptoms of a poor XML design is often that XSD doesn't allow you to validate it.

You can do it with XSD 1.1 assertions if you really must:

```
<xs:assert test="every $e in child::* 
                 satisfies local-name($e) = 
                           concat('element_', count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
```

but I would really recommend changing the design. The sequence numbers give no extra information and make it more difficult to process the XML, whatever processing API or language you use.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, w3schools.com is a great place to learn XML, XML Schema, etc.  It's free to read, and dependable.

the key word to search is sequence.  See: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_sequence.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness: **this is a really bad XML design.**
One of the purposes of XML is to avoid this.

It also seems that this scheme of naming is not supported in XSD 1.0 at all indicated by this SO answer: ["Can I use regular expressions in XML Schema element names?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13937087/1305969).

The XPath expression matching this kind of element names would be

```
concat('element_',position())
```

but this cannot be represented in XSD 1.0 due to the above circumstances. Maybe there is a way in XSD 1.1.